# eigenvector equivalence for subspace of matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

There is an eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ in matrix A, which is $3x3$, with corresponding eigenvector $x_a = 1/\sqrt{2}(1,0,1)$.  The same eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ can be found in the subspace of matrix A, which is $2x2$, with corresponding eigenvector $x_b = 1/\sqrt{2}(1,1)$.

Question:  Could a zero be added to eigenvector $x_b$ such that it equals $x_a$?

Matrix A = \begin{pmatrix}
 1   & 0       & \lambda               \\
  0         & 0 & 0                \\
  \lambda         & 0       & 1          \\
  \end{pmatrix}
and the subspace of Matrix A = \begin{pmatrix}
 1   & \lambda                     \\
  \lambda         &   1                 \          \\
  \end{pmatrix}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how you define equal, obvious $x_a \ne x_b$ in the exact sense since they DEFINITELY aren't the same thing (one has 3 dimensions the other has 2)!

But...

That doesn't mean they are not exhibiting some similar behavior. If you restate "equal" as "equal under a particular model" then the question becomes interesting again. It might be the case that there is a function $g$ out there such that $g(x_b) = g(x_a)$ where $g$ encodes some information about the matrix you are working with and the matching eigenvalues.

Comment: ok, thank you... do you by any chance know how this might apply in perturbation theory and the degenerate subspace?

Comment: not off the top of my head head you should add those in as tags, and write the matrices too for more information

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at the edit if you get a chance